# Error LNK2019 in cpp file while csv file is attached to the file

Tags: c++, c, csv, c++11, lnk2019

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl readCSVtovector(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::vector<class Record,class std::allocator<class Record> > &)" (?readCSVtovector@@YA_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAV?$vector@VRecord@@V?$allocator@VRecord@@@std@@@2@@Z) referenced in function _main  quiznewcsv  C:\Users\H A I E R\source\repos\quiznewcsv\quiznewcsv\main.obj  1
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Your tags are screwy: this has nothing to do with "C++11" or with "CSV".  Very simply, you're getting a [link error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573818/421195).  Because you failed to link the .obj that implements function "readCSVtovector()" into your .exe, and/or you failed to declare function "bool readCSVtovector()" correctly in your main.cpp.

Comment: You included both C and C++ tags.  Are you mixing the languages?  The C language doesn't support namespaces, nor `std::string`.  I recommend you update your tags.

Comment: Are you compiling and linking in C?  The `std::basic_string<char>` is not part of the C language; it's C++.  You should try compiling as C++ (and updating the tags).